# To show the existence of a decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have following two statements:

(1) For each $x_0>0$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)\geq \epsilon$ for each $x\geq x_0$.

(2) For each $\epsilon>0$, $f(x)\leq \epsilon~$ for some $x>0$.

From the above two statements, how can I show that that there is a decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ such $x_n\to 0$ and $f(x_n)\to 0$.

My attempt:

The first statement can be written as:

For $x_0=\frac{1}{n}$, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$f(x)<\epsilon\Rightarrow x<\frac{1}{n} $$.

The second statement can be written as:

For $\frac{1}{n}$, there is $x_n>0$ such that $f(x_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: What did you try? Where were you stuck? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=how+to+ask+a+good+question

Comment: @AnneBauval I added my attempt.

Comment: Don't you assume $f\ge0?$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, indeed $f$ is a function from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Then please edit your question to tell it.  And what about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

By (2), there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ of positive numbers such that $f(x_n)\to0.$

By (1), such a sequence converges to $0.$

Every positive sequence converging to $0$ admits a decreasing subsequence.